# How to average column data for multiple columns in text files?

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a tab delimited data text file in the following format:

```
Depth    Temp    Salinity
0.30    28.30    31.90
0.30    28.30    31.90
0.30    28.20    31.90
0.30    28.20    31.90
0.40    28.20    32.00
0.40    28.00    32.00
0.50    28.00    31.90
0.60    28.00    32.00
0.70    27.90    32.00
0.60    27.90    32.10
```

What I want to achieve is to obtain any lines where there are duplicate values in the Depth column and put them into a list/s. Then from that list/s I will average these values for each column (not averaging the Depth column), sort the values by Depth, and then output all this back into the original data file format. So in the example file above, the output would be:

```
Depth    Temp    Salinity
0.30    28.25    31.90
0.40    28.10    32.00
0.50    28.00    31.90
0.60    27.95    32.05
0.70    27.90    32.00
```

I understand I need to use .readlines() to grab the relevant lines, but how do I only grab duplicate lines?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary where the key is the depth.

```
lines = [
"0.30    28.30    31.90",
"0.30    28.30    31.90",
"0.30    28.20    31.90",
"0.30    28.20    31.90",
"0.40    28.20    32.00",
"0.40    28.00    32.00",
"0.50    28.00    31.90",
"0.60    28.00    32.00",
"0.70    27.90    32.00",
"0.60    27.90    32.10"
]

dict = {}
for line in lines:
    depth, temp, salinity = map(float, line.split())
    old = (0,0,0)
    if depth in dict: old = dict[depth]
    dict[depth] = (old[0]+1, old[1]+temp, old[2]+salinity)

for key in dict:
    tri = dict[key]
    print(str(key) +"   "+str(tri[1]/tri[0])+"   "+str(tri[2]/tri[0]))
```

Comment: this works well! The output from this was unsorted, how do I sort it by Depth?

Comment: @Luk45, `for key in sorted(dict):` should do it

Comment: but you really shouldn't use dict as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford to read the entire file into memory, [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) may simplify your code:

```
from itertools import groupby

lines = [map(float, line.split("\t")) for line in open('file.txt')]
print lines[0].strip() # print out header
key_fun = lambda(x):x[0]
sorted_lines = sorted(lines[1:], key=key_fun)
for k,g in groupby(sorted_lines, key=key_fun):
    g = list(g)
    mean_temp = sum(x[1] for x in g) / len(g)
    mean_salinity = sum(x[2] for x in g) / len(g)
    print "%f\t%f\t%f" % (k,mean_temp,mean_salinity)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution and link, looks like I have some reading to do!

Comment: you don't need to use a list comprehension for the sums. `sum(x[1] for x in g)` will work fine

Answer (score 0):

use numpy can simplify calculation:

```
import numpy as np
with file("data.txt", "rb") as f:
    titles = f.readline().strip().split()
    data = np.loadtxt(f)
data = data[np.argsort(data[:, 0])]
split_index = np.where(np.diff(data[:,0])>0)[0]+1

print "\t".join(titles)
for a in np.split(data, split_index):
    print "\t".join("%f" % x for x in np.average(a, axis=0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @user772649, I've never used numpy before so I'll have to test this solution out!